Problem with Jenkins, the system can not run the file?
I am newbie with Jenkins and here is my problem. I downloaded the code from internet and here is the code's link
https://github.com/kavisuresh/SampleExpressApp
I followed all the steps, but when I ran the program, I met this error as you can see in the picture

I do not know the problem, maybe because I did not install jdk to Jenkin, or when I followed the tutorial, I forgot any step?
Do you get any idea for me?
Thank you in advance.
I tried to follow the Jenkin's tutorial but I have an error.

can you give a little more context here. whats the goal here is it to check the jenkins set up whether it can run jobs or not?

from the above screenshot the issue is inconclusive, please give us more context.
from first impression, its unable to find a file i guess.
try this jekinsfile - just add ls -la to list the files and pwd to understand your current location/path
pipeline{
  agent any
  stages{
    stage('Build'){
      steps{
        nodejs('Node'){
          echo 'Building Application.....'
          sh '''
             pwd
             ls -la
             '''
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

